# Node package.json script compiled sass file extname change

Tags: node.js, package.json

Is it possible to get compiled css file path in **"component-sass"** script and change file extname to `.php` and add prefix `<?php return'` and suffix `';`

```
"scripts": {
    "components": "run-p component-sass",
    "component-sass": "cross-conf-env sass $npm_package_config_components_src:$npm_package_config_components_dist --style=compressed",
    "watch:component-sass": "cross-conf-env onchange \"$npm_package_config_components_src/**/*\" -e \".DS_Store\" -- npm run components",
 },
```